# How to manage multiple contacts in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

I have 100 contacts in my Pidgin account in two folders. How to move all contacts from one folder to another and how to remove multiple contacts at once? I've tried one by one, but it takes years to complete.

Comment: I agree. I'd really like to know the best practice for this.